# Conditional column with loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe like this

```
ID, DateIndex, Qty
1, 1, 10
2, 1, 15
3, 1, 20
4, 1, 30
1, 2, 14
2, 2, 13
3, 2, 14
4, 2, 12
1, 3, 1
2, 3, 60
3, 3, 19
4, 3, 12
....
```

I want to output a table like this

```
ID, DateIndex, Qty, n-1, n-2, n-3, n-4....
1, 3, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0....
2, 3, 60, 1, 1, 0, 0....
3, 3, 19, 1, -1, 0, 0....
4, 3, 12, 0, -1, 0, 0....
```

The conditional is that if the qty value of that dateindex is less than the qty value for that ID at dateindex-1 it will return -1, if it is greater than it will return 1, and if it is the same or not found then it will return 0.

Here is what I have so far

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=['Date']).sort_values(['Date', 'ID'])

df['DateIndex'] = df['Date'].rank(method='dense')
```

I think I will need to define a function and use apply but not sure how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just `groupby` and call `diff` with each group. However, Your output indicates you want to compare `n` against `n-1, n-2, n-3....` groups and assign each to separate columnns. Therefore, you need to function to call `diff` multiple time with different values:

```
def shift_count(x, i):
    m = x.groupby('ID').Qty.diff(i)
    return  (m.gt(0).astype(int) - m.lt(0).astype(int)).rename('n-'+str(i))
```

This function return a series. Call it `n` time within a list comprehension to create list of series. Finally `pd.concat` it with original `df`

```
n = 4
list_series_diff = [shift_count(df, i) for i in range(1, n+1)]
pd.concat([df] + list_series_diff, axis=1)

Out[162]:
    ID  DateIndex  Qty  n-1  n-2  n-3  n-4
0    1          1   10    0    0    0    0
1    2          1   15    0    0    0    0
2    3          1   20    0    0    0    0
3    4          1   30    0    0    0    0
4    1          2   14    1    0    0    0
5    2          2   13   -1    0    0    0
6    3          2   14   -1    0    0    0
7    4          2   12   -1    0    0    0
8    1          3    1   -1   -1    0    0
9    2          3   60    1    1    0    0
10   3          3   19    1   -1    0    0
11   4          3   12    0   -1    0    0
```

Comment: This works but freezes up my PC on large data sets with rows ~1300*3000 and n~1300, or it bugs out at i~650 and restarts shell. Any advice?

Comment: It happens when it tries to concat